# GeneratorExit Exception when debugging any() line

Tags: python-3.x, exception, visual-studio-code, generator, any

I am getting the `Exception has occurred: GeneratorExit` message **only when debugging** *(in VSCode)*.

```
anyIsTitle = any(word.istitle() for word in ['notitle', 'Title'])
```

The problem is with `any()`. It runs fine when not using it, say with a normal for loop. I am also loading some heavy stuff into memory while on this line.

Can someone explain why this could be happening?

Comment: This probably needs a `vscode` tag of some kind

Comment: Sounds like `VSCode` issue. Can you try a different IDE?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try and update!

Comment: it would help to show the complete code that fails

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue when debugging Python code in `vscode`, with the following code: `assert any(timescale in s for s in ["ms", "s", "m", "h"])`. Seems like there's an issue with the combination of `any()` and `x for y in  z`.

Comment: The same for "all" in vscode: `def test_vs_code(self): self.assertTrue(all(x == 1 for x in [1, 2, 3, 4]))` Prompts for GeneratorExit exception.

Comment: chiming in (with upvote) to note i am experience this issue in the same manner as described by @FilipS.